# ap with iwd at boot - ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, networking, wireless

Environment:
Ubuntu 22.04 on apu2 (pcengines) HW with 2 miniPCI express – WLAN Cards
One of the WLAN interfaces should be an AP, the other one is a WLAN Client, connected toward a different AP. I’m trying to switch from wpasupplicant and hostapd towards iwd.
In general this solution does work, but it does not survive a reboot. I need to enter the following instructions to enable the AP again

```
iwctl device wlan0 set-property Mode ap
iwctl ap wlan0 start-profile <profilename>
```

The Profile is stored in `/var/lib/iwd/ap`
The client wlan works after boot.

Data:

```
lshw -C network
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA986x/988x 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 04:f0:21:XX:XX:XX
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.15.0-50-generic firmware=10.2.4-1.0-00047 ip=x.x.x.x latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:59 memory:d0000000-d01fffff memory:d0200000-d020ffff
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA986x/988x 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlan1
       version: 00
       serial: 04:f0:21:xx:xx:xy
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.15.0-50-generic firmware=10.2.4-1.0-00047 ip=x.x..x latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:61 memory:d0400000-d05fffff memory:d0600000-d060ffff
… and some eth interfaces …. 


iwctl device list (after boot)
                                    Devices
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Name                Address             Powered   Adapter   Mode
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  wlan0               04:f0:21:xx:xx:xx  on        phy0      station
  wlan1               04:f0:21:xx:xx:xy   on        phy1      station
```

expected

```
iwctl device list
                                    Devices
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Name                Address             Powered   Adapter   Mode
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  wlan0               04:f0:21:xx:xx:xx   on        phy0      ap
  wlan1               04:f0:21:xx:xx:xy   on        phy1      station
```

main.conf

```
more main.conf | grep -v ^#

[General]
EnableNetworkConfiguration=false
[Network]
 EnableIPv6=false
```

What do I need to configure to make iwd starting with one station and one ap ?